# corrupted `code` formatting after posting new question (on SO)

Tags: support, markdown, code

it happened to me few times lately that **after submitting new question** the formatting of inserted code was **corrupted**. I am 100% sure that it looked ok at the time I clicked `Post Your Question` button.

I did copy&paste from my text editor (I use tabs to indent the code) into SO question box and then I was fixing the formatting.

I do not have any screen shots but you can probably go through all the versions of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126673/hash-assignment-when-key-value-are-stored-in-an-array-ruby) where I was reminded via comment to fix the formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Markdown interprets lines indented by four spaces as code blocks. Tabs are pretty much ignored and will make your code look sloppy. And you don't want that.

Before you cut and paste your code from your favourite text editor, swap out all the tabs for four (4) spaces.

Then you can drop it in and the code will look good too.

Comment: This is all part of the excellent plan to stop people coding with tabs ;-)

Comment: the MarkdownSharp will correctly normalize tabs to spaces in most (all?) cases now

Answer (score 1):

In that specific case, you had some lines with only three spaces at the start. A code block must retain at least four spaces at the start of each line.

Comment: @bobince: I am sure that the code look ok before I sent it out. What was saved is different story